# How to document the "non-nullableness" of reference types in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, instances of reference types are passed to functions as a nullable pointer. Consider for example:

```
public void f(Class classInstanceRef)
```

In most cases, the function will expect a non-null pointer (in 95% of all cases in my experience). What is the best way to document the fact that this function expects a non-null pointer?

**Update**: thanks a lot for your responses so far!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) Make sure the method rejects any null

```
if (instanceRef == null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException("instanceRef");
}
```

2) Add

```
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"> is thrown 
/// when <paramref name="instanceRef"/> is <c>null</c></exception>
```

> The exception that is thrown when a
>   null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) is passed to a method that does
>   not accept it as a valid argument [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx)

Comment: Instead of `ArgumentException` you should use `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `ArgumentNullException` instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to throw an ArgumentNullException instead of ArgumentException?

Comment: This overload of the ArgumentNullException constructor takes the name of the argument, not an exception message, so it should be new ArgumentException("Class");

Answer (score 18):

In .NET 4, you will have the ability to use **[code contracts](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/Code-Contracts)**, which are meant for just this sort of thing:

```
Contract.Requires(classInstanceRef != null);
```

In the meantime, I think proper documentation and throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the code contracts library:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

It enables you to specify pre-conditions to your code and have it verified using static analysis of the code-base:

```
Contract.Requires( x ! = null );
```

The library will be included in .NET Framework v 4 and there are commercial licenses for earlier versions of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

```
Debug.Assert(classInstanceRef != null);
```

Comment: That's now what I'd call documentation... How often do you check the debug output of your program ?

Comment: If you compile in debug mode this pops up an assertion-failure dialog at runtime.  How much more in your face do you want it??

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does stuff
/// </summary>
/// <param name="classInstanceRef">some documentation</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when the <paramref name="classInstanceRef"/> is null.</exception>
public void f(Class classInstanceRef)
{
  if (classInstanceRef == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("classInstanceRef");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(classInstanceRef == null) { throw new NullReferenceException("classInstanceRef"); }
```

?

```
///<remarks>classInstanceRef cannot be null</remarks>
```

Comment: You shouldn't throw a NulLReferenceException (as per guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx ).  Prefer instead the use of ArgumentNullException.

Comment: indeed, lazy thinking on my behalf there... wouldn't do it in my own code.